# Ansible dynamic inventory - how to inject values to an inventory source

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory, ansible-awx

Here is some background first.

I have a dynamic inventory which pulls data from an external source. I have various playbooks which does a few tasks using this inventory, and I run them by either an adhoc `ansible-playbook` command, and via [Ansible AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx).

When testing connectivity to managed hosts, I can run commands such as `ansible -m ping -i inventories/ linuxnode.servers.fqdn`, and this works totally fine. I also have an inventory sync in AWX, and that works fine as well.

This works using an `inventory source` within `inventories/` in YAML format, wherein I pass some values to the custom inventory script `the_custom_plugin`. Sample YAML file `datacenter1.yml`:

```
plugin: the_custom_plugin
url: "https://externalapp.servers.fqdn"
username: poweruser
privatekey: secretpassword
```

Now, I want to get rid of the username and password for obvious security reasons, and instead, hide them:

1. In environment variables when running via the `ansible-playbook` command; and
2. In AWX credentials when running via `AWX`.

**The problem is**, there doesn't seem  a way to inject values to variables in the inventory souce. Even a very simple change like this does not work (i.e. the custom plugin fails):

```
plugin: the_custom_plugin
url: "https://externalapp.servers.fqdn"
temp_username: poweruser
username: "{{ temp_username }}"
privatekey: secretpassword
```

Is there any `secret YAML syntax` for an inventory source file which uses an external plugin? Or is the issue somehow in the custom plugin code? I'm very much perplexed that this doesn't even work:

```
temp_username: poweruser
username: "{{ temp_username }}"
```

Cheers.